# Understanding too many open files and current limits

Tags: ulimit, resource-limiting, lsof

A Java application will sometimes have issues after the logs point to too many open files.

Okay, let's look at some limits...

```
    cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max -> 200000
    ulimit -n -> 1024
    ulimit -u -> 2000000
    ulimit -Hn -> 4096
    ulimit -Hs -> 1024
```

Let's see what a filter for top open file handles says...

```
    sudo lsof | awk '{print $1 " " $2; }' | sort -rn | uniq -c | sort -rn | head -15
```

The top entries show

```
    4757521 (database driver used by Java application redacted) 1230
     112760 (http thread of java application) 1230
      54289 (another java thread) 1230
        ...
```

I thought the file-max is the global maximum file handles that can by open system-wide. The first entry of the lsof-sorted output would appear to exceed that limit, but it's still running at the moment. I seem to recall cases with other systems where overloading and hitting too many open files meant I couldn't even run commands because there were no available file handles to assign to new processes...yet in this case the numbers don't seem to add up. What am I missing in diagnosing resource use in this case? Is it juggling per-thread/per-process/per-user numbers? I'm not asking how to increase the limit, as that's something to be set with syslimit/ulimit/system conf...rather, I am looking to understand why the limits reported seem to be ignored according to current use reported by lsof and how to track down actual limits and resource use by the application reporting problems.

Comment: What happens if you ignore `mem` (memory-mapped) entries? I *think* those wouldn't have FDs allocated to them (and memory-mapped files will include things like the executable itself, the shared libraries that it links to, etc.)

Comment: For example, on my system, `sudo lsof | wc -l` => 12278,  `sudo lsof | grep -vw mem | wc -l` => 2864, `cat /proc/sys/fs/file-*` => 2147483647 and `2976 0 2147483647`. That output without `mem` entries is close enough to the number of actual files opened (the first column in `/proc/sys/fs/file-nr`, that I think `mem` entries don't count.

Comment: @muru `sudo lsof |grep -vw mem |wc -l` shows `5007202`, `sudo lsof |wc -l` shows `5082431`, while `cat /proc/sys/fs/file-*` shows `200000` and `5632 0 200000` ...